# Can't SSH to a VirtualBox VM

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I set up a Ubuntu VirtualBox VM with a Host-Only Adapter. The Ubuntu user is `remy`. I checked the connection via `ping` : OK.

I did from the VM (using this time a NAT network connexion to connect to Internet):

```
sudo apt install openssh-client openssh-server
```

I checked if the `sshd` is running with

`ps -A | grep ssh`

Output :

`<pid> ? 00:00:00 sshd`

I tried to connect from the Mac OS Host to the Guest server with : `ssh -v remy@192.168.99.101`.

Output :

```
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.99.101 [192.168.99.101] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/remy/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Ubuntu-10 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.99.101:22 as 'remy'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:FP93K2351YfhImrQqD8X6PbjX3tyFc8xixJL5Vd/Vic
The authenticity of host '192.168.99.101 (192.168.99.101)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:FP93K2351YfhImrQqD8X6PbjX3tyFc8xixJL5Vd/Vic.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

It's my first time with SSH ... Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Did you answer the question with yes?
(literaly - yes must be spelled out)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! I am very ashamed, this is probably the worst issue on StackExchange ..!